# How many SQL queries WP Super Cache make to serve cached page?

Tags: plugins, cache

WP Super Cache plugin generate page and save html of this page to static file and if needed this file is served instead of dynamically generate this page each time.

**Does WP Super Cache plugin make any extra SQL queries during serving the cached page?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've received an [answer about it from Donncha O Caoimh](http://ocaoimh.ie/2012/04/24/wikipedia-irish-style/#comment-696371) - developer of the WP Super Cache plugin:

> If using mod_rewrite to serve cached files then there won't be any queries executed. The page might load images that require queries but the cached html itself won't require queries.
>
> If using PHP mode than I think it won't need any or many queries but I can't remember right now.

So there is 0 extra sql queries and the question is closed.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you the answer to this off the top of my head, but if you want to look at the SQL queries (among other things) executed for any given page load, check out the [black box debug bar plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/blackbox-debug-bar/).  I think that the [debug bar plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/) might have similar functionality as well.

Regardless of the number of additional queries a caching plugin makes, it should still cut down on your page load time...don't want to cut off your nose to spite your face, right?

If you really want to focus on getting your queries down, you should look into database caching, which can be done by any number of plugins.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I know about those plugins. I even wrote [similar plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/info/) :).
But those plugins does not show needed info because cached page is the static file which is generated once first time when page was generated. Those plugins will wrote in the source code of the page the number of sql queries needed to generate page only for first time and and not number of sql queries needed to generate cached page. So those plugins does not show info about cached page and that is why I decided to ask this question here.